# use of undeclared NSForegroundColorAttributeName error in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my  i want to i'm displaying a text in text view.Also i want to change the color of some sentences in that text.When i'm using the code below i'm getting the error NSForegroundColorAttributeName undeclared and i also tried using kCTForegroundColorAttributeNamevalue but is also showing undeclared error.How to remove this error.Can any one help me please.

```
enter code here


NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]   initWithString:@"Paint a picture together, alternating every minute (use a timer to keep track)"];
[string addAttribute:kCTForegroundColorAttributeNamevalue:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,8)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(8,10)];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(10,5)];
```

Comment: You have to `#import` the CoreText framework. Also, the values need be `CGColor`s, not `UIColor`s.

Comment: @ishhh: Why don't you accept some answers to the questions you have asked?

Comment: The framework is given for MAC OS not for iOS. So please give answer for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the AppKit framework? Also, include `NSAttributedString.h` in your header file.

Comment: Thamks.i can't found APPKit framework.After adding the  NSAttributedString.h it is showing no such file or directory.

Comment: The error won't go away unless you include the framework. See the documentation - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/_index.html.

Comment: The question has the iphone tag.  The AppKit framework is not part of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS its a PITA...
Here is how I am making a white color and applying it to a range

First

```
 #import <Foundation/NSAttributedString.h>
```

Then

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

 CGFloat components[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
 CGColorRef whiteColor = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, components);

 CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

 [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(__bridge id)whiteColor range:titleRange];

 CGColorRelease(whiteColor);
```

I happen to be using ARC, so take out the __bridge if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `CoreText/CoreText.h` to get the declaration of `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName`.

The value must be a `CGColor`, not a `UIColor`.

There's less casting to do this way:

```
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute((__bridge void*)string, CFRangeMake(0, 8),
    kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
```